# Need the help of an EXPERT in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, product, configurable-product, product-images, custom-options

i am currently trying to wireframe a very custom website e-store, i will try to be as direct and clear as possible to my question:

Is it possible to have for example, in a product page where you are selling a 1 piece canvas product where you have 3 pictures as a mockup of that 1 canvas example, and then on the side you have multiple options, one of them is to split that canvas in 3 pieces (multi-canvas), switching those 3 mockup photos to the 3 new ones that display the multi-canvas instead? To this question im almost certain its possible but its always good to ask again because it relates to my REAL doubt.

Is it possible in the Product list page, have a filter that we would choose to filter 1 piece canvas, and it would only display images of that, and then there was another filter that would display only the 3 pieces canvas. Is it possible to do this **without** creating multiple products? In this scenario i only gave 2 options but in reality it would have many more, just wondering if its possible to do that kind of filtering without having to create different product per each circunstance.

Im not asking how to do it, im sure its really hard and needs an expert, just asking if its possible.

Thank you so much for your feedback in advance :)